# How to divide one column into two even row columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, pivot, rows, divide

I have a query that returns nth rows in one column. I would like to divide the rows in half and put them in another column.

| ITEM |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A1 |
| A3 |
| A4 |
| A5 |
| A6 |
| A7 |
| A8 |
| A9 |
| A10 |
| A11 |

Convert to

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 |
| A3 | A4 |
| A5 | A6 |
| A7 | A8 |
| A9 | A10 |
| A11 |  |

Comment: PIVOT is not the right option to get what you want, as PIVOT aggregates (sum, avg) results in the cells below the headers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col1 
FROM (select col1,row_number() over(order by col1) rownum from Test) a
LEFT JOIN (Select col1, lag(col1) over(order by col1) previous from test) b
ON a.col1 = b.previous 
WHERE rownum%2=1
```

being Test the table and col1 the column, this is basically selecting the odd rows and joining them with the following row.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to also want to remove duplicates.  So, I would suggest aggregation using `dense_rank()`:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then col1 end),
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then col1 end)       
from (select col1,
             dense_rank() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from test
     ) t
group by ceiling(seqnum / 2.0);
```

Note:  This assumes that the ordering is based on the `col1` value.

Comment: Thank you. That works too. How would you use this if I need more than 2 columns?

Comment: You would change the `2.0` to `n` and add additional `max()` expressions in the `SELECT`.